# Texmaker Shortcuts not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: latex

Even the simple ctrl+F is not working... I tried installing texmaker from software center and [xm1math web site](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux), but shortcuts still doesn't work...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Install the Qt5 version of texmaker (*at this date it is the one you get from ubuntu-software-center*) and always run it from terminal using:

`env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker`

**or** (*a permanent solution*)

Edit `texmaker`:

Open nautilus as root:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Navigate to `usr/share/applications/texmaker` , *right click* on it, *properties*, and change on *Command* `texmaker %F` by `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker %F`
[image]`

Comment: This is unfortunately not working on a fresh install of ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: @E.P. ....... I'm really disappointed with texmaker, they should have tested with all current versions of Ubuntu. I don't use 16.10 and I don't plan to use it, so I can't help those with your problem. If you find the solution, post here. Just one question, did try this procedure with 16.04 and it worked?

Comment: I never tried 16.04, I skipped straight from 15.10 (for which I did the remove qt5 thing, making for remarkably bad visuals). If I have time I'll try to test this off of the live USB and maybe compare with 16.04; if anything interesting comes up I'll report it here.

Answer (score 15):

You don't have to install the older version, you just need to remove the `appmenu` package for QT5:

```
sudo apt remove appmenu-qt5
```

P.S. I am not sure if it can cause problems for other applications on your system. It didn't cause any problem in my end.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding solution 2 of Vitor, you can also edit the launcher shortcut to TexMaker:

```
/usr/share/applications/texmaker.desktop
```

and change the line

```
Exec=texmaker %F
```

to

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker %F
```

Comment: Works for me. The menu will then be attached to the actual window and not available at the top bar as usual - but at least it works. What a funny bug.

Comment: @displayname yep, that's right, this will "break" the global menu, because you are explicitely disabling it - as it is its fault (at least kind of) that the shortcuts are broken... But this is definitely the safest and cleanest solution which should not have any side-effects. Upvote for this one! Removing non-application specific packages like the `appmenu-qt5` package without any need doesn't look particularly clever to me...

Answer (score 3):

from terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/texmaker.desktop
```

you will see

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Office;Publishing;Qt;X-SuSE-Core-Office;X-Mandriva-Office-Publishing;X-Misc;
Keywords=Editor;Latex;
Exec=texmaker %F
GenericName=LaTeX Editor
Comment=LaTeX development environment
Icon=texmaker
MimeType=text/x-tex;
Name=Texmaker
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Now change the line

```
Exec=texmaker %F
```

to

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker %F
```

and then save and exit

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
sudo apt remove appmenu-qt5
```

Worked for my fresh ubuntu 16.04 installation.

Comment: We don't know if it may interfere on other applications. @vitor Solution is safer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias in the `.bashrc` or create the file `~/.bash_aliases` and define the alias:

`alias texmaker='env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker'`

save it, exit and source it. From the home directory, do:

`$. .bashrc`

`$. .bash_aliases`

Done. Now opening Texmaker from the terminal will work perfectly.

Note: In a way it's very similar to @Vitor Abella's method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be Qt5 and setting `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` did not fix it for me on Ubuntu 16.10 for me, so here is my solution:

- Remove Texmaker:  `sudo apt-get remove texmaker texmaker-data`
- Download the latest Debian version of Texmaker from: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux (In my case, I downloaded `texmaker_debian_jessie_4.5_amd64.deb`
- Install it: `sudo dpkg -i texmaker_debian_jessie_4.5_amd64.deb`

Note: the package might have some dependencies like `libqt4-opengl` and `libqtwebkit4` that you might have to install manually

Comment: Did you mean "did not fix it"? It didn't fix it for me either on 16.10, but the alternate .deb you pointed to did work.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Ubuntu 16.10, I have installed version 4.5 for Ubuntu 14.04 and shortcut are working. I suppose the other versions for Qt4 will work too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ubuntu 16.10, and adding the `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=` to `/usr/share/applications/texmaker.desktop` did not work. Nevertheless, since Ubuntu 17.04 the problem seems to be gone - even without the `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=`, hotkeys work for me in Texmaker.