# Texmaker shortcuts don't work 16.04

Tags: 16.04, latex

But latex is very difficult to use without shortcuts. I also tried to use the solutions mentioned in the last post by someone about the same problem, but still it doesn't.

Comment: What's this "last post" you mentioned? Can you link to it so that we know what you have tried?

Comment: Ever tried [TexStudio](http://texstudio.org/)? Plenty of shortcuts! I use it everyday, in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions and information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/786280/texmaker-shortcuts-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04